R.java not imported from library module
I have an app that contains 2 modules. One is library module and other is app module. I tried to import library module through build.gradle dependencies tag of app module, it works fine.
But when I added Namespace tag in each of build.gradles, it does not work.
app level build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace "abc.ux.demo"}

lib level build.gradle 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace "abc.ux"}

In gradle.properties:
GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION = 8.2.2

kotlin_version = 1.9.23

In both the build.gradle files I am using compose dependencies as below:
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true

    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.11'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def compose_ui_version = "1.6.4"

In app level build.gradle, I added dependency of lib as below :
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':uxlib')

In my app level build.gradle when I try to access a string/style from lib module, I am see error as "Unresolved reference: UXDatePickerDialogTheme" like below :
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTheme(R.style.UXDatePickerDialogTheme)  

When I try to add manually like below , it works fine. But its difficult to change in all places manually . Is there a way I can rectify this issue or is this issue related to gradle version:
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTheme(abc.ux.R.style.UXDatePickerDialogTheme)  

How can I fix this?
